# Generate and display random message – JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

For the website that I am creating, I am looking to have a random welcome message be generated using a JavaScript array and be displayed on the screen using the innerHTML property. So far, I've created the array with the messages, but I'm stuck on how to select a random one, then insert it using the innerHTML property. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Can you update your question with the relevant code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting random value from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example

```
document.getElementById("your-elements-id").innerHTML = "<p>" + yourArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * yourArray.length)] + "</p>";
```

Put it inside your window.onload or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/ywnv00xc/1/

```
const messages = ['message1', 'message2', 'message3', 'message4'];
const randomIndex = Math.round(Math.random()*messages.length);
document.getElementById("your-elements-id").innerHTML = messages[randomIndex];
```

Comment: [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: This has an an off by one issue, occasionally out of bounds, should not be used

Answer (score 0):

From MDN:

```
const getRandomArbitrary = (min, max) => {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};
```